# PHP dynamic navigation submenu

Tags: php, html, css

I have created a dynamic nav menu for a website. The menu loads to each page from a separate file, therefore i am using php required on all pages. I am trying to highlight the menu item when visitor is on each page and i cannot use JS or jQuery. All should be done in PHP, CSS and HTML only.

So far, i have the following function in the navigation file:

```
<?php
  function setActive($name){
    global $pageName;
    if ($pageName == $name){
      echo "class='active' ";
    }

  }

?>
```

And example of a menu:

```
<ul>
  <li ><a <?php setActive ('v')?> href="v.php">Home</a></li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">cd</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a  href="a.php">a</a></li>
                <li><a  href="b.php">b</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

The function works for main menu, but i cannot get it work for submenu pages. I want the item cd to highlight when visitor lands on page a.php or b.php.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: You can try using `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` to find in php if you are on a.php or b.php. Forexample `if ($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] == "a.php"){?>/*put something here or set a variable here to be used for the style to highlight*/<?php}`.

Comment: you could keep group of submenu in array and using in_array($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI],array('a.php','b.php'))